# Replace more than two dots as unicode ellipsis

Tags: python, regex, python-re

How do I replace two or more periods in a string with a unicode ellipsis?

e.g.

```
Hey. -> Hey. (does not change)
Hey.. -> Hey…  (all of  these change)
Hey... -> Hey…
Hey.... -> Hey…
Hey..... -> Hey…
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Where did you get stuck? What did you get and what did you expect?

Comment: A simple match and replace will do it. Did you try anything on your own?

Comment: `re.sub( '\.\.\.+', '…',x)`, obviously.

Comment: You have said 2 dots in the question but your example results have 3 dots.

Comment: @PubuduSitinamaluwa firs of it says _more than two dots_ second Op wants to replace those dots with an ellipsis (three dots)

Comment: `re.sub(r'[.]{2,}', f'\N{Horizontal Ellipsis}', 'Hey.')`

Comment: `r'\.{3,}'` if you mean *more than two* dots, `r'\.{2,}'` if you mean *two or more* dots.

Comment: Closers, can you clarify how this question is unfocused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it.  It uses a regular expression to match two or more dots.

```
import re
s='Hey.....'
new_string = re.sub(r'[.][.][.]*', '…', s)
print(new_string)
```

Comment: Your regexp matches 2 or more, not 3 or more (because `*` matches 0 or more). You can use the `{3,}` quantifier to mean 3 or more.

Comment: oops, I typed "three" thinking of ellipses dots, but the RE is correct.  Fixed.